# Project Setup for Github/Openshift/Spring MVC

Tags: spring, git, spring-mvc, github, openshift

This is a general question, which I'm sure has been asked before, but all the resources I'm finding suffer from the typical coder problem of assuming I know things that I don't know.

I'm trying to use Openshift to deploy a Spring MVC project from a Github repo.  What I don't know is what my github link is supposed to contain.

I initially assumed that the github repo should simply contain the code of my project, where I'm linking all of my development code to.  However, when applying this the result is a 404 page with no additional information.

Does the github repo require a WAR?  Does it need to be set up in a specific way?  I've been able to successfully deploy this project from a WAR to another server, so I know the code is working properly, but I can't seem to find any documentation on the expectations for project design that openshift has for my github repo.

Am I doing this right?  Is my problem with the github contents, or is it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You should try creating a default project for whichever java server cartridge you are using, and look at the structure.  It's a standard Maven project, but there is some difference in the pom.xml so that it knows how to deploy the war file it compiles.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, the command `$ rhc app create MyApp jbossews-2.0` should create that default project structure for me, correct?  Would a good next step be to simply copy/paste my existing project into that workspace?

Comment: You should then clone that project to your local machine and see how it works, inspect the default application layout and the pom.xml to see what is needed for your application to deploy correctly, especially the "openshift" profile at the bottom of the pom.xml, that actually deploys your war file after it's created.